# Display modal bootstrap before call to action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

My HTML code is like this :

```
<form action="form2_action.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name </td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="age" name="age" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form> 


<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-save" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Are you sure to book this tour?</b></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:30%">First Name</td>
                        <td height top="40" style="width:70%" id="first_name_modal"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td height="40" id="last_name_modal"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td height="40" id="age_modal"></td>
                    </tr>                 
                </table>        

                <p class="debug-url"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript code is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {
        var first_name_modal = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
        var last_name_modal = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
        var age_modal = document.getElementById("age").value;

        if(first_name_modal!="" && last_name_modal!="" && age_modal!=""){
            $("#confirm-save").modal("show");
            $('#first_name_modal').text(first_name_modal);
            $('#last_name_modal').text(last_name_modal);
            $('#age_modal').text(age_modal);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Demo is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/wjo8yjhb/

When I input data and click button submit, The system directly call action `form2_action.php`. I want before system call to action, system display modal bootsrap first.

So, How to display modal bootstrap before call to action?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you want what the user can already see popping up in a modal when they expect the form to submit?

Comment: @Popnoodles, so that the user does not enter data wrong

Comment: Look up form validation

Comment: @Popnoodles, I've been using html5 validation required. But display the details of user input in the modal bootstrap before the save was a request from my client. So, I have to follow my client requests.

Answer (score 1):

The form action take always the precedence, you need to avoid this using te preventDefaul function like so:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var first_name_modal = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
        var last_name_modal = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
        var age_modal = document.getElementById("age").value;

        if(first_name_modal!="" && last_name_modal!="" && age_modal!=""){
            $("#confirm-save").modal("show");
            $('#first_name_modal').text(first_name_modal);
            $('#last_name_modal').text(last_name_modal);
            $('#age_modal').text(age_modal);
        }
    });
```

I have also update your fiddel so this works fine for you! Have a nice day.

Comment: It's not working. When I input data dan click button submit, the system display modal bootstrap. Then, I click button save changes in modal, the system not success call action form2_action.php. Besides, if I do not fill the data in textfield, required html5 not appear.

Comment: I can not follow very well. Try to explain what is occurring and I will try to look at your fiddle for a solution.

Comment: @mosestoh I have posted an other answer to your second question please read it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The second behavior you describe has the same problem as thefirst one. You are still clicking on the document so you need here also to do the following:

```
$('#saveBtn').on('click',function(e){
         e.preventDefault()
      //here has to come the code to submit this form 
})
```

I have update the fiddle again for you.

It is possible to do it But I really don't understand why you want to do this, in fact you are only showing the user input in the modal.